# Interacting with OleObjects/embeded controls VSTO, VBA Conversion

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vba, vsto

I'm working on converting an old VBA project into a C# VSTO.  I know a lot of the code has to go out of the window, but I was hoping to still use the layout and objects that had been embeded into the sheet.  Examples of the objects include controlbuttons, labels, images, etc.

All of these persist nicely when I choose the document as a template when making a new project.  I run into the problem in that I can't seem to select or reference any of these objects.  For example there's a button in the middle of a sheet.  If I open the sheet in VS2012, I can see the button.  I can even "highlight" it but not select it.  If I right-click on the button to pull up the properties, it will bring up the properties for the sheet, not the button.  I can't resize them or move them around (not that I want to).

I also can't seem to reference them in code, ie `...Sheet1.ControlButton1...` or `...Sheet1.OleObject(n)...` will never refer to anything.  If I open up the workbook directly from the solution folder and click on the same control I can see properties, and the formula bar in Excel reads `=EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1","")`.

I've also not been able to loop through all the OleObjects and just display their names.  Clearly where ever the collection is that is storing these I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Workbook.Shapes collection

Edited as per the comments below.  This works:
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("CommandButton1");

Comment: I tried that.  I can add a shape, and then when I loop through the shapes, the new one seems to be the only one there.

Comment: Ok, awful workaround, but could you create little wrapper functions in your actual VBA project that do nothing other than return a reference to these objects?  Then you could use Object obj = Application.Run(FunctionName) from within C#.

Comment: Worth a try.  I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Apparently `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("CommandButton1");` works but `Me.OLEObjects("CommandButton1") from within the code on Sheet1 doesn't work... Don't know why. Your answer got me there if you want to edit I'll accept.  I don't suppose you know how to get the click event from an OLEObject button.  I've tried adding events and deligates but it throws an exception every time.

Comment: Glad that you're making progress.  Hmmm...  You could get the click macro to fire a built in Excel event and then catch the Excel event in .Net.  Irritating that Excel makes you jump through these hoops though.